# Change the color of highlighted/selected text

Tags: css

I would like to change the color of highlighted text on my page.

Currently, this is how I am approaching this:

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am running into problems where I am unable to change the background color of highlighted text if strings are separated by a linebreak, like so:

```
Hello
  World
```

An example of this can be found on my current web application project: http://term.qt.io by doing CTRL+A (Select-All for most browsers) to highlight all the text. You will notice that it appears gray in some areas but blue in others. I would like all the highlighted text to be a gray background rather than blue in some areas.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Because for me, every thing is gray (on Chrome).

Comment: Okay, added a screenshot.

Comment: This would seem to be working as expected in my opinion. All the selected text has a gray background. The blue area is not part of the selection - this is the (empty) background of the outer container.

Comment: Might be a bug with Chrome!

Comment: It looks like it is just highlighting til the end of the line in your `div` or `p` or whatever element you are using. AFAIK there is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but note that you need to separate the rules for `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` and repeat the styles for each one for it to work.

Comment: @Zack T.: Correct. `::selection` is extremely unreliable for highlighting anything *but text*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `span` is what's breaking it. Coding it like this works fine:

```
<p class="prompt">Welcome to term.
    <br>
    <br>
    login as: <span class="input blinker">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

And it's better semantics IMO.

Comment: If I took this approach, how do I prevent `<p>` from line breaking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. `<p>This</p><p>works</p><p>too</p>`
http://jsfiddle.net/QxRSx/. Note: I had a hiccup in FF when trying to include `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` in the same line of CSS. `-moz` seems to prefer its own line/declaration.